# IONIC : TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation

I have an issues while try to add geolocation function in my app. I'm using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation

In `home.ts`, call this findUserLocation() in ionViewDidLoad():

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

...

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.findUserLocation()


  }

findUserLocation(){
    let options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 25000
    };

     this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {

      this.location = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      };

      this.mapsProvider.init(this.location, this.mapElement);

     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
       });   

   }
```

And this is my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
    }
  }
```

And then when i run ionic serve, there's error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Geolocation.getCurrentPosition (index.js:10)
    at HomePage.webpackJsonp.263.HomePage.findUserLocation (home.ts:45)
    at HomePage.webpackJsonp.263.HomePage.ionViewDidLoad (home.ts:34)
    at ViewController._lifecycle (view-controller.js:487)
    at ViewController._didLoad (view-controller.js:370)
    at NavControllerBase._didLoad (nav-controller-base.js:789)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
```

Please help for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Geolocation plugin is only available after the `deviceready` event has fired. You can find this [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation).

To solve your issue, you have to use Geolocation ONLY after `Platform.ready()` completes. Try to modify your code to something like this:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(
  private geolocation: Geolocation
  public platform: Platform,
) {}

ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.findUserLocation()
   });
}
```

Also, make sure you have installed the plugin properly by running the following commands, then re-building/running your app:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install @ionic-native/geolocation --save
```

Comment: Have done with your suggestion, but still not work 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Geolocation.getCurrentPosition (index.js:10)
    at HomePage.webpackJsonp.272.HomePage.findUserLocation (home.ts:45)
    at home.ts:33

Comment: These versions work fine for me:
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.15.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
Can you confirm it's failing using these versions, as well?